# Read QT .pro file within program

Tags: qt

I would like to know if there is some way to read a variable defined in the .pro file of a QT project, during runtime. the thing is that Im trying to compile cuda, for just one architecture (Sm_21), and I want to decide on runtime to use the cuda device that has that capability.

.pro file:

```
QT       += core gui opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = hello-opengl
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
       mainwindow.cpp \
       glwidget.cpp \



HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
            glwidget.h \



FORMS    += mainwindow.ui


CUDA_ARCH = sm_21           # Type of CUDA architecture
```

I would like some way to use this CUDA_ARCH variable in my .cpp. For example

```
if (CUDA_ARCH == sm_21)
  then pick device 0
else
  pick device 1
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: as a last measure, you can always open .pro file and parse/replace CUDA_ARCH value with QFile for instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add preprosessor macro with the value, in *.pro* do:

```
CUDA_ARCH = sm_21           # Type of CUDA architecture

DEFINES += CUDA_ARCH=$${CUDA_ARCH}
```

So this is basically equivalent to adding this to your C code:

```
#define CUDA_ARCH sm_21
```

---

Then in code you can just use the macro, like you'd use any *#define*, for example:

```
// enum is most convenient way to get the architectures as symbols
enum CudaArchEnum { sm_21, sm_22};

//... initialize a variable
enum CudaArchEnum value = CUDA_ARCH; // value = sm_21;

//.. or from your question
if (CUDA_ARCH == sm_21) {
  // pick device 0
} else {
  // pick device 1
}
```

You can also put it to a variable as string, like this:

```
const char *CudaArchStr = #CUDA_ARCH; // CudaArchStr = "sm_21"
```

Comment: Thank you! that did it! Although I had to add some back slashes, so that the define would be a string. Otherwise I got a compilation error, saying that the sm_21 was not declared in that scope.
 CUDA_ARCH=\\\"$${CUDA_ARCH}\\\"

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
DEFINES += CUDA_ARCH_SM_21
```

and ask in the code for

```
#ifdef CUDA_ARCH_SM_21
```

I do not think its possible to directly create a "global" variable in .pro file. But you could just set your global variable CUDA_ARCH in the #ifdef block

```
#define CA_SM_21 0
#define CA_SM_OTHER 1
#ifdef CUDA_ARCH_SM_21
  int CUDA_ARCH = CA_SM_21
#elseif
  int CUDA_ARCH = CA_SM_OTHER
#endif

if(CUDA_ARCH == CA_SM_21)...
```